# Split string by delimiter, but not if it is escaped

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

How can I split a string by a delimiter, but not if it is escaped? For example, I have a string:

```
1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4
```

The delimiter is `|` and an escaped delimiter is `\|`. Furthermore I want to ignore escaped backslashes, so in `\\|` the `|` would still be a delimiter.

So with the above string the result should be:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2\|2
[2] => 3\\
[3] => 4\\\|4
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use dark magic:

```
$array = preg_split('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|~s', $string);
```

`\\\\.` matches a backslash followed by a character, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` skips it and `\|` matches your delimiter.

Comment: Is there documentation for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`?

Comment: @eyelidlessness: You can have a look into the [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt). Search for `(*SKIP)`. You'll find the documentation for all those backtracking control verbs like *SKIP, *FAIL, *ACCEPT, *PRUNE, ... there.

Comment: +1 @NikiC both for providing a link to the PCRE documentation and making me want to read it.

Comment: I was trying to do it without backtracking control verbs. However, since it's not possible to use negative lookbehind assertions with a non-fixed length, that one becomes pretty hard. (Well unless you use Anton's solution below.) Guess you'd better do some magic, just like NikiC did. ;-)

Comment: `+1` - amazing answer. But shouldn't the 3rd index of the array be `4\\\|4`? -- [It is `4` right now](http://3v4l.org/iDpMV)

Comment: @AmalMurali `a\\\a` will be *two* backslashes after PHP parsed the string ;) `a\\\a` is the same as `a\\\\a` to PHP :)

Comment: @MCEmperor You might look into the [`\K` escape sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex). See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qK1aK0).

Comment: `(*SKIP)(*F)` is terrific... +1 :)

Comment: @AmalMurali You will need to escape the input even more for the actual result to be correct. http://3v4l.org/VboWD

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `split(...)`, it's IMO more intuitive to use some sort of "scan" function that operates like a lexical tokenizer. In PHP that would be the `preg_match_all` function. You simply say you want to match:

1. something other than a `\` or `|`
2. or a `\` followed by a `\` or `|`
3. repeat #1 or #2 at least once

The following demo:

```php
$input = "1|2\\|2|3\\\\|4\\\\\\|4";
echo $input . "\n\n";
preg_match_all('/(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\|])+/', $input, $parts);
print_r($parts[0]);
```

will print:

```
1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2\|2
    [2] => 3\\
    [3] => 4\\\|4
)
```

Comment: I always have weird edge cases when trying to match instead of split. For example, with `+`, you remove empty elements: `a||c`. With `*` you may get empty elements you don't really want (though not here, I think). Somehow, it never works quite the same...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought you were escaping the pipe in `[^\\|]`. I'm a little off.

Comment: You raise a good point Kobi. No, I wouldn't change the `+` into `*` (I guess to many empty strings'd be matched). If the corner case of an empty string between pipes can occur, I'd handle it like this `...|(?<=^|\|)(?=$|\|)`, where `...` is the existing regex.

Comment: +1 This probably is the more intuitive way to solve this particular problem. But I found that the dark magic approach also has many other nice use cases (especially in quick & dirty regexing). For example if you want to scan some files but don't want to match in strings and comments you can simply SKIP those. (And there's obviously the problem with the empty elements, but Kobi already said that.)

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, here is a universal solution. It is based on NikiC's idea with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```php
function split_escaped($delimiter, $escaper, $text)
{
    $d = preg_quote($delimiter, "~");
    $e = preg_quote($escaper, "~");
    $tokens = preg_split(
        '~' . $e . '(' . $e . '|' . $d . ')(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|' . $d . '~',
        $text
    );
    $escaperReplacement = str_replace(['\\', '$'], ['\\\\', '\\$'], $escaper);
    $delimiterReplacement = str_replace(['\\', '$'], ['\\\\', '\\$'], $delimiter);
    return preg_replace(
        ['~' . $e . $e . '~', '~' . $e . $d . '~'],
        [$escaperReplacement, $delimiterReplacement],
        $tokens
    );
}
```

Make a try:

```php
// the base situation:
$text = "asdf\\,fds\\,ddf,\\\\,f\\,,dd";
$delimiter = ",";
$escaper = "\\";
print_r(split_escaped($delimiter, $escaper, $text));

// other signs:
$text = "dk!%fj%slak!%df!!jlskj%%dfl%isr%!%%jlf";
$delimiter = "%";
$escaper = "!";
print_r(split_escaped($delimiter, $escaper, $text));

// delimiter with multiple characters:
$text = "aksd()jflaksd())jflkas(('()j()fkl'()()as()d('')jf";
$delimiter = "()";
$escaper = "'";
print_r(split_escaped($delimiter, $escaper, $text));

// escaper is same as delimiter:
$text = "asfl''asjf'lkas'''jfkl''d'jsl";
$delimiter = "'";
$escaper = "'";
print_r(split_escaped($delimiter, $escaper, $text));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdf,fds,ddf
    [1] => \
    [2] => f,
    [3] => dd
)
Array
(
    [0] => dk%fj
    [1] => slak%df!jlskj
    [2] => 
    [3] => dfl
    [4] => isr
    [5] => %
    [6] => jlf
    )
Array
(
    [0] => aksd
    [1] => jflaksd
    [2] => )jfl'kas((()j
    [3] => fkl()
    [4] => as
    [5] => d(')jf
)
Array
(
    [0] => asfl'asjf
    [1] => lkas'
    [2] => jfkl'd
    [3] => jsl
)
```

**Note:** There is a theoretical level problem: `implode('::', ['a:', ':b'])` and `implode('::', ['a', '', 'b'])` result the same string: `'a::::b'`. Imploding can be also an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I devised a solution:

```
$array = preg_split('~ ((?<!\\\\)|(?<=[^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)+)) \| ~x', $string);
```

But the black magic solution is still three times faster.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you measured the performance of your regex vs. that of the black magic solution?

Comment: [`Warning: preg_split(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`](https://3v4l.org/qlGmE)

Answer (score -1):

Regex is painfully slow. A better method is removing escaped characters from the string prior to splitting then putting them back in:

```
$foo = 'a,b|,c,d||,e';

function splitEscaped($str, $delimiter,$escapeChar = '\\') {
    //Just some temporary strings to use as markers that will not appear in the original string
    $double = "\0\0\0_doub";
    $escaped = "\0\0\0_esc";
    $str = str_replace($escapeChar . $escapeChar, $double, $str);
    $str = str_replace($escapeChar . $delimiter, $escaped, $str);

    $split = explode($delimiter, $str);
    foreach ($split as &$val) $val = str_replace([$double, $escaped], [$escapeChar, $delimiter], $val);
    return $split;
}

print_r(splitEscaped($foo, ',', '|'));
```

which splits on ',' but not if escaped with "|". It also supports double escaping so "||" becomes a single "|" after the split happens:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b,c [2] => d| [3] => e )
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked? Also "...markers that *you hope* will not appear in the original string"