# Split a string, excluding some characters

Tags: php, php4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string by delimiter, but not if it is escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243778/split-string-by-delimiter-but-not-if-it-is-escaped)

I have a string generated form ibm informix database which is separated by pipe `|` characters and there are some data errors, which means there are **backslash + pipe** inside the data. I want to split these strings only from the pipe sign, not from **backslash + pipe** `\|` or other signs with the pipe.

This is my code, but it works only for the pipe character:

```
foreach(glob("ssbstat.unl") as $file)
{ 
    $c=0;       
    if(($load = fopen($file, "r")) !== false)
    { 
        $line = fgets($load);           
        $count= count(explode('|', $line));
        echo $fm= str_repeat('%[^|]|', $count)."%s\n";      

        do
        {
            echo $line;
            print_r($line);
            if($c++>10) break;
        } while ($line = fscanf($load, $fm));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: PHP4? Time to upgrade...

Comment: Which "other characters" did you need to exclude, what do you mean "or other signs with the pipe"? Was `\|` the *only* thing you want to ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `preg_split`. This piece `[^\\\\]` specifies that pipes with backslashes should be ignored (the four backslashes are required  for proper escaping. You can add any other character you want to ignore inside the `[]`.

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?<![\\\\])\|/', 'This\|is a|test|string'));
```

Comment: This won't work! a string like `'This\|is a|test|string'` will return this: `Array ( [0] => "This\|is " [1] => "tes" [2] => "string" )` because you say any char before `|` which isn't a backslash will be a part of the split function too, so it is away. That's why you should use preg_replace in before (like I have answerd)

Comment: Good catch. I really should have been using a negative lookbehind. `preg_replace` isn't necessary. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
<?php
$line = preg_replace("/([^\\\])\|/", "$1 |", "Hi \|error\| man|ok man|perfect man");
print_r(preg_split('/[^\\\]\|/', $line));
```

Will output:

```
Array ( [0] => "Hi \|error\| man" [1] => "ok man" [2] => "perfect man" )
```

**Testet!**

Edit: Like Maerlyn said, this is also possible:

```
<?php
$line = "Hi \|error\| man|ok man|perfect man";
print_r(preg_split('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|~s', $line));
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace backslah + pipesign with a placeholder, then explode by pipesign, then replace back placeholder with backslah + pipesign

Comment: What kind of placeholder do you suggest? It would have to be something that couldn't possibly appear in the data or your last replacement may corrupt it.

Comment: anything that is unlikely present in your string. Something like "{[%my_great_placeholder%]}" or so

Comment: i have done it but there are about 100000 lines. it is taking hell of a  time to so this. i want a short method. can this regular expression be developed???

Comment: @MassimilianoArione: It would *probably* work, but the "probably" is what keeps it from being a good idea; one that you would actually feel safe using. Unless you can be 100% sure what the data contains (or does not contain), there's no possible placeholder that you could use safely. Regular expressions are the solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: regexp is not faster than simple str_replace, indeed it's slower.

Comment: if there is a way to edit this regular expression. it can be done. only to select pipe sign. not other signs with pipe

Comment: @lankitha: What does "other signs with pipe" mean? Each character is of course going to be next to another one, whether it's a space, newline, tan, backslash, etc. You need to be more explicit, maybe show some sample data.

Comment: @Madmartigan probability is just a matter of betting. I can bet whatever you want that your text is not containing the string "{[%#my_super_great_flicking_placeholder#%]}"

Comment: But guess what, now this page contains that very text. If I were running your idea on this page (of course, without *kowing* what the page contained) it would fail. Gambling is for fools! :)

Comment: I think you're completely missing my point... but I'll retire my argument.

Comment: No, I see it. But I just think you can afford a good probability just with a good choice of text. Ehi, you can also change it to something dynamic, maybe including the current date in it, or even a sha1.