# Using REGEX with escaped quotes inside quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a PHP `preg_match_all` and REGEX question.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$string= 'attribute1="some_value" attribute2="<h1 class=\"title\">Blahhhh</h1>"';

preg_match_all('/(.*?)\s*=\s*(\'|"|&#?\w+;)(.*?)\2/s', trim($string), $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

That does not seem to pickup escaped quotes for the instance that I want to pass in HTML with quotes. I have tried numerous solutions for this with the basic quotes inside quotes REGEX fixes, but none seem to be working for me. I can't seem to place them correctly inside this pre-existing REGEX.

I am not a REGEX master, can someone please point me in the right direction?

The result I am trying to achieve is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => attribute1="some_value"
            [1] =>  attribute2="<h1 class=\"title\">Blahhhh</h1>"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => attribute1
            [1] =>  attribute2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => some_value
            [1] => <h1 class=\"title\">Blahhhh</h1>
        )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: May we know what exactly are you trying to do in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
'/(.*?)\s*=\s*(\'|"|&#?\w+;)(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\2~/'
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

The closing quote should not be prepended by `\`. Gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => attribute1="some_value"
            [1] =>  attribute2="<h1 class=\"title\">Blahhhh</h1>"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => attribute1
            [1] =>  attribute2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => "
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => some_value
            [1] => <h1 class=\"title\">Blahhhh</h1>
        )
)
```

This regex ain't perfect because it of the entity you but in there as delimiter, like the quotes it can be escaped as well with `\`. No idea if that is really intended.

See also this great question/answer: [Split string by delimiter, but not if it is escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243778/split-string-by-delimiter-but-not-if-it-is-escaped/6243797#6243797).

Comment: This one works well and even with \n characters. Thanks for the great answer Hakre!