# Assitance with regexp

Tags: php, regex

I feel shamed but I'm still not clear with some regexp aspects.
I need to parse text file which contains a number of string literals of `@"I'm a string"` format.
I've composed simple pattern `/@"([^"]*)"/si`. It works perfect, preg_match_all returns a collection. But obviously it doesn't work properly if string literal contains escaped quotes like `@"I'm plain string. I'm \"qouted\" string "`. Would appreciate for any clue.

Comment: I actually tried your escaped string and the pattern seems to work

Comment: yes, the pattern works, but value grabbed by placeholder ([^"]*) is not as expected

Comment: `preg_match_all('/@"(.*)"$/si', $text, $match);` .?

Comment: You're right. but using this it works for me: /@"(.*)"/si

Comment: Seems to be ok : `preg_match_all('/@"([^"]|\\")*"/si', $text, $match);`. Try it here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d62a5e00484640badbb8f48ece0c98870ab66b49

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6243778/592540

Comment: Just have to adapt a little... `preg_match_all('/(@"([^"]*|(\\"))")/si', $text, $match);` is working on your new string example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59eb5bc6e0ad36ec8919d356e805f73b21ef084a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use case for Freidl's classic "unrolled loop": (**EDIT** fixed grouping for capture)

```
/"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"/
```

This will match the quoted string, taking backslash-escaped quotes into account.

The full regex you would use to match a field (including the `@`) would be:

```
/@"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"/
```

But be careful! I often see people complaining that this pattern doesn't work in PHP, and this is because of the slightly mind-melting nature of using a backslash in string.

The backslashes in the above pattern represent a *literal* backslash that needs to be passed into PCRE. This means that they need to be double-escaped when using them in a PHP string:

```
$expr = '/@"((?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)"/';

preg_match_all($expr, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]); // this will show the content of all the matched fields
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FbhMLn)

**How does it work?**

...I hear you ask. Well, lets see if I can explain this in a way that actually makes sense. Let's enable `x` mode so we can space it out a bit:

```
/
  @             # literal @
  "             # literal "
    (           # start capture group, we want everything between the quotes
      (?:       # start non-capturing group (a group we can safely repeat)
        [^"\\]  # match any character that's not a " or a \
        |       # ...or...
        \\.     # a literal \ followed by any character
      )*        # close non-capturing group and allow zero or more occurrences
    )           # close the capture group
  "             # literal "
/x
```

This really important points are these:

- `[^"\\]|\\.` - means that every backslash is "balanced" - every backslash must escape a character, and no character will be considered more than once.
- Wrapping the above in a `*` repeated group means that the above pattern can occur an unlimited number of times, and that empty strings are allowed (if you don't want to allow empty strings, change the `*` to a `+`). This is the "loop" part of the "unrolled loop".

**But the output string still contains the backslashes that escape the quotes?**

Indeed it does, this is just a matching procedure, it doesn't modify the match. But because the result is the *contents* of the string, a simple `str_replace('\\"', '"', $result)` will be safe and produce the correct result.

However, when doing this sort of thing, I often find I want to handle other escape sequences as well - in which case I usually do something like this to the result:

```
 preg_replace_callback('/\\./', function($match) {
     switch ($match[0][1]) { // inspect the escaped character
         case 'r':
             return "\r";

         case 'n':
             return "\n";

         case 't':
             return "\t";

         case '\\':
             return '\\';

         case '"':
             return '"';

         default: // if it's not a valid escape sequence, treat the \ as literal
             return $match[0];
     }
 }, $result);
```

This gives similar behaviour to a double-quoted string in PHP, where `\t` is replaced with a tab, `\n` is replaced with a newline and so on.

**What if I want to allow single-quoted strings as well?**

This has bugged me for a very long time. I have always had a niggling feeling that this could be more efficiently handled with backreferences but numerous attempts have failed to yield any viable results.

I do this:

```
/(?:"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)")|(?:'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)')/
```

As you can see, this is basically just applying basically the same pattern twice, with an OR relationship. This complicates the string extraction very slightly on the PHP side as well:

```
$expr = '/(?:"((?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)")|(?:\'((?:[^\'\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\')/';

preg_match_all($expr, $subject, $matches);

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; isset($matches[0][$i]); $i++) {
    if ($matches[1][$i] !== '') {
        $result[] = $matches[1][$i];
    } else {
        $result[] = $matches[2][$i];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Where `\\.` would incline any weird slash-escapes like `\t`, `\n` etc. +1

Comment: @Allendar The beauty of this is that it will only break on an unescaped double quote, any other combination of backslash escapes will be left untouched. I will try and break down how it works in a comprehensible way.

Comment: Thanks, You've made my day, Dave! non-capturing group is exactly what I was looking for and that was missed part of my knowledge about regexp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative lookbehind - match everything until you find a quote not preceded by a backslash. This is in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] strings = new String[]{"@\"I'm a string\"", "@\"I'm plain string. I'm \\\"qouted\\\" \""};

    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@\"(.*)\"(?<!\\\\)");
    System.out.println(p.pattern());

    for (final String string : strings) {
        final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm a string
I'm plain string. I'm \"qouted\"
```

The pattern (without all the Java escapes) is : `@"(.*)"(?<!\\)`

Comment: Wasn't the question asked for PHP?

Comment: Regex is regex right? The regex pattern works, the OP just needs to escape whatever needs escaping in PHP.

Comment: PHP Regex actually has different rules, requiring extra escape quotes. Besides that it might confuse the person asking the question if he/she is absent the knowledge of JAVA, even tho it might make sense to most of us; it's not to commonly assume it's so. Your regex itself is correct tho :)

Comment: @Allendar I thought that was not to do with the `String` itself rather than the regex - i.e. in order to get a string literal that looks like the pattern you need to do the escapes differently.

Comment: You are correct on that matter, but he tagged his question with PHP. It's commonly known Regular Expressions have some weird outcomes in different languages. I just wanted to point that out. No worries tho, I like your answer :)