# catching __('<string>') inside simple and double quote

Tags: php, regex, internationalization

I use a function `__()` to translate string, and I added an interface to automatically find all theses translation in all files. This is (supposed to be) done with the following regex:

```
<?php
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
`
  __\(
    (?<quote>               # GET THE QUOTE
    (?<simplequote>')       # catch the opening simple quote
    |
    (?<doublequote>")       # catch the opening double quote
    )
    (?<param1>              # the string will be saved in param1
      (?(?=\k{simplequote}) # if condition "simplequote" is ok
        (\\'|"|[^'"])+      # allow escaped simple quotes or anything else
        |                   #
        (\\"|'|[^'"])+      # allow escaped double quotes or anything else
      )
    )
    \k{quote}             # find the closing quote
    (?:,.*){0,1}          # catch any type of 2nd parameter
  \)
  # modifiers:
  #  x to allow comments :)
  #  m for multiline,
  #  s for dotall
  #  U for ungreedy
`smUx
LOD;
 $files = array('/path/to/file1',);
 foreach($files as $filepath)
 {
   $content = file_get_contents($filepath);
   if (preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches))
   {
     foreach($matches['param1'] as $found)
     {
       // do things
     }
   }
 }
```

that regex does not works for some string double quoted containing an escaped simple quote (`\'`). It seems in fact, whatever the string is simple or double quoted, the condition is considered as false and so the "else" is always used.

```
<?php
// content of '/path/to/file1'
echo __('simple quoted: I don\'t "see" what is wrong'); // do not work.
echo __("double quoted: I don't \"see\" what is wrong");// works.
```

for file1, I expect to have both strings found, but only the double quoted works

**Edit** added more php code to make it easier to test

Comment: could you post some valid and invalid examples along with the expected output?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243778/split-string-by-delimiter-but-not-if-it-is-escaped the top answer provides an example on how to capture escaped sequences.

Comment: I just edited @AvinashRaj . I hope this is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 2.

```
__\((['"])((?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*)\1\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wU9nH7/1)

**Explanation:**

- `__\(` Matches the literal `__(` characters.
- `(['"])` Captures the following double or single quotes.
- `(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*` Matches the escaped double or single quotes (*quotes is based on the character inside the group index 1*) or `|` not of the character present inside the capturing group `(?!\1).` zero or more times.
- `\1` refers to the char inside the 1st captured group.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. This works on the demo but not in my code... trying to figure out why

Comment: Can you explain me this : According to the doc (http://php.net/manual/fr/regexp.reference.assertions.php)  I understand `(?!\1).)` as "match anything (the `.`) except if there is a quote before" which is supposed to append at the first char after the quote. What do I miss ?

Comment: `(?!\1).` means match any character `.` but not the one inside group index 1. If the group index 1 contains double quotes, `(?!\1).` would match any character except double quotes. Likewise, for the single quotes..

Comment: ok thanks a lot ! I just understood the lookahead things, meaning "make a break. now, let's see what the next character looks like... is it allowed? ok you can continue"

Answer (score 0):

Avinash Raj's solution is more elegant and probably more efficient (so I validate it), but I just found my mistake, so I post the solution here:

```
<?php
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
`
  __\(
    (?<quote>               # GET THE QUOTE
    (?<simplequote>')       # catch the opening simple quote
    |
    (?<doublequote>")       # catch the opening double quote
    )
    (?<param1>              # the string will be saved in param1
      (?(simplequote)       # if condition "simplequote" 
        (\\'|[^'])+         # allow escaped simple quotes or anything else
        |                   #
        (\\"|[^"])+         # allow escaped double quotes or anything else
      )
    )
    \k{quote}               # find the closing quote
    (?:,.*){0,1}            # catch any type of 2nd parameter
  \)
  # modifiers:
  #  x to allow comments :)
  #  m for multiline,
  #  s for dotall
  #  U for ungreedy
`smUx
LOD;
```