# php replace group of double backslash

Tags: php, regex

how to replace group of double backslash in a string to `*`

for example:

```
\\\\a ->  **a
\\\a  ->  *\a
\\a   ->  *a
\a    ->  \a
```

I try use both `str_replace` and `preg_replace` but it failed at the second case

```
str_replace('\\', '*', $str);
preg_replace('/\\\\/', '*', $str);

=> `\\\a` -> `**a`
```

---

the reason i want to do this is i want something same as [Split string by delimiter, but not if it is escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243778/split-string-by-delimiter-but-not-if-it-is-escaped) but

```
$str = '1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4';
$r   = preg_split('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\|~s', $str);
var_dump($r);
```

give me.

```
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2\|2' (length=4)
  2 => string '3\|4\\' (length=6)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
```

i expect something like

```
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2\|2
  [2] => 3\\
  [3] => 4\\\|4
```

php 5.4.45-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal backslash in PHP single-quoted strings must be declared with 2 backslashes: to print `1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4` you need `$str = '1|2\\|2|3\\\\|4\\\\\\|4';`.

In a regex, the literal backslash can be matched with 4 backslashes.

Here is an updated [PHP code](http://ideone.com/xR5wvn):

```
$str = '1|2\\|2|3\\\\|4\\\\\\|4';
// echo $str . PHP_EOL; => 1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4
$r   = preg_split('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\|~s', $str);
var_dump($r);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "2\|2"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "3\\"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "4\\\|4"
}
```

And to obtain `**a` from `\\a` you can thus use

```
$str = '\\\\a';
$r   = preg_replace('~\\\\~s', '*', $str);
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/UYRBoE)

Comment: let say that my original string is `'1|2\|2|3\\|4\\\|4';` how can i convert it to `'1|2\\|2|3\\\\|4\\\\\\|4';` ?

Comment: I do not know how you can [tell a `2\|2` from `3\|4`](https://ideone.com/pjTLHG). Even if you convert the string into a byte array with [`$byte_array = unpack('C*', $str);`](https://ideone.com/HLTE1b), you will not find the difference.